# SQL Server stored procedure to update two databases on differrent servers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, replication

The two servers have exactly the same setup (databases/tables etc). I want one of the tables (on both servers) to have the same data. So the update procedure on server A should also be able to update server B.

I want this to happen with each call to that update stored procedure with out any time delay. Any thoughts?

I did look at the other questions but this aspect of multiple servers seems to be un-answered. Any thoughts?

Edit to clarify: The Server B always should follow Server A. (Also, the stored procedure that updates A can be edited to update B... if the Dbs were on the same server... this is a different case.)

Comment: You can accomplish this by setting up replication.

Comment: Can both be updated, or will Server A always get updated and Server B should always match Server A exactly?

Comment: @JNK  : Server A is the main server and Server B should always match A. I am only talking about a single table.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SQL Server High Availability solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202). **Log Shipping**, **Failover Cluster**, or **Database Mirroring** may fit your particular needs. It depends whether you need a failover for backup or an online DB for reporting.

> *Side Note:* **Database Mirroring** will be [deprecated in future SQL Server versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202) and should be avoided. It is being superseded by [**AlwaysOn Availability Groups**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510230) in SQL Server 2012.